# Image Upload Background Processing Using Queues

Tags: laravel

So I have a web application where users will be submitting very large files, and when being submitted the files are queued up to be processed by the back end. I want to send a notification to the user once their specific upload has been processed, but i'm having trouble coming up with a solution when multiple users are submitting at once. I supposed I could query the jobs database to see if it is the last of that specific upload id, but I feel there is something more optimal. Here is my code:

```
    if($request->hasfile('filename'))
    {

        foreach($request->file('filename') as $file)
        {

            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path=public_path().'/images/';

            $image = new Image;
            $image->filename = $name;
            $image->save();

            $currentID = $image->id;

            $file->move($path, str_pad($currentID, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'.$name);

            AnalyzeImage::dispatch($image);
        }

     }
```

Comment: Can you clarify, what do you mean by saying "i'm having trouble coming up with a solution when multiple users are submitting at once."

Comment: Essentially whenever I finish a job I want to check and see if it is the last job queued up by a specific user submission, and if it is send a notification to a user when their files are done. I'm pretty new with laravel, but I imagine I could use this:   Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) { but I don't really know how to differetiate between different submissions

Comment: If uploading user is signed in, you can just get him/her by Auth::user(), and get the email from this and send notification. Yes you use Queue::after